# Can traits be loaded in plugins?

Tags: plugin-development

I have a number of different models that have custom validation methods, some of which are shared across models.

Due to the combinations I can't use class inheritance to share those methods, so I wondered if traits are supported and if so, what the convention would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Traits](https://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) are just a PHP thing not related to Craft at all so yes, you could use them.  But you'd be limiting your plugin to PHP 5.4+ only since that's when they were introduced.

Craft 2.x supports back to [PHP 5.3](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/requirements#server-requirements).

You might also want to look at Yii's [Behaviors](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/44/behaviors-events/#hh1), which have similar functionality to traits and works with PHP 5.3.

Craft 2.x uses a [few behaviors](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference#craft.app.etc.behaviors) of its own.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't aware of behaviours so will take a look at that first.